# Annoying mouse icon next to cursor touch screen

Tags: windows

This is a touch screen monitor. I can't seem to get rid of the mouse image next to the cursor. It follows the cursor. Is there a way to remove it?

[Mouse next to cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPUtk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is facile.
Go to https://github.com/TooTallNate/SGF-HTML-Engine/blob/master/dist/blank.cur
Hit the download button and either choose \windows\cursors if you have control where the downloads go, or make note of the folder/directory location, i.e. \users\user1\Downloads

[image: Blank.cur Github download]

Next, you'll want to go to the control panel > mouse
Or hit Windows Key +R (or bring up a run dialogue from the Start Menu) and type the portion inside quotes, "rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL main.cpl" and hit Enter.
Navigate to the Pointers tab or use Control +Tab 1 time to arrive there.

Next, navigate to the Customize section and go through which instance you want the blank cursor to appear for.  For example do you wish it to be under normal operation, or when the computer is busy, or for every instance?  Though I wouldn't recommend this as the changing of a cursor to another cursor, for example and I-beam or hourglass are visual cues to what the computer is doing and/or expects.  In this scenario you would double click on each listing in the scroll box: Normal Select, Help Select and double click or press enter on each entry.  The browse dialogue box will come up for you to choose the .cur or .ani file.

If you previously dragged and dropped or pasted the downloaded .cur file into c:\windows\cursors (or wherever Windows lives on that PC) you can scroll through the list and select the blank.cur.
If, instead, the newly downloaded file blank.cur is in your Downloads directory, navigate there and choose that file.

This should do ya.
If you're not the IT guy or supervisor and it's in a work scenario, be sure you run it by the higher ups or "powers that be", first.

Comment: Also, there exists the possibility the particular touch screen manufacturer has an overlay feature which can be customized through either the control panel, much like the one walked through in my answer, or there exists a System tray icon in the lower right corner of Windows taskbar which can be clicked on and customized.  Likely there's a (un)selectable checkbox for "mouse overlay to track location".